# Minesweeper, Bombcount method

Tags: java, game, matrix, minesweeper

I have a method which checks all of its surrounding squares and returns the number of bombs around it. It uses a long list of `if` statements, which is pretty ugly and probably inefficient.

```
       public int countArround(){
    int bombNum = 0;
    //x=0 y=1 works
    if(((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation, yLocation+1)!=null)&&
        (((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation, yLocation+1)).getBomb())){
        bombNum++;
    }
    //x=1 y=1
    if(((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation+1, yLocation+1)!=null)&&
        ((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation +1, yLocation+1)).getBomb()){
        bombNum++;
    }
    //x=1 y=0 works
    if(((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation+1, yLocation)!=null)&&
        ((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation+1, yLocation)).getBomb()){
        bombNum++;
    }
    //x=1, y=-1 works
    if(((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation+1, yLocation-1)!=null)&&
        ((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation+1, yLocation-1)).getBomb()){
        bombNum++;
    }
    //x=0 y=-1
    if(((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation, yLocation-1)!=null)&&
        ((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation, yLocation-1)).getBomb()){
        bombNum++;
    } 
    //x=-1, y=-1 works
    if(((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation-1, yLocation-1)!=null)&&
        ((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation-1, yLocation-1)).getBomb()){
        bombNum++;
    } 
    //x=-1, y=0 works
    if(((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation-1, yLocation)!=null)&&
        ((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation-1, yLocation)).getBomb()){
        bombNum++;
    }
    //x=-1 y=1 works
    if(((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation-1, yLocation+1)!=null)&&
        ((SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation-1, yLocation+1)).getBomb()){
        bombNum++;
    }
    return bombNum;
```

I was wondering how this can be cleaned up. I cannot seem to get it into an `if/while/for` statement.

Comment: Related question: [Neighbors of a matrix element](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/33042/9357)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A double-for-loop over `x` and `y` seems appropriate.

Also, it seems like a good idea to assign `(SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(...)` to a variable.

```
int bombNum = 0;
for    (int xOffset = -1; xOffset <= 1; xOffset++)
   for (int yOffset = -1; yOffset <= 1; yOffset++)
   {
      if (xOffset == 0 && yOffset == 0)
      {
         continue;
      }
      SmartSquare neighbour = (SmartSquare)board.getSquareAt(xLocation+xOffset, yLocation+yOffset);
      if (neighbour != null && neighbour.getBomb())
      {
         bombNum++;
      }
   }
return bombNum;
```

Comment: Beutiful thank you very much, 
Do you know any good sites/articles/books about code 'elegance'?

Comment: Glad I could help. No, unfortunately I don't know of any such resources.

Comment: @Babbleshack **Clean Code** by Robert C. Martin: http://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: I find this non-indentation to be a sneaky way to disguise the nested for-loop. Indent the inner loop! If you _really_ want the characters in your code to line up vertically, put extra spaces between the "for" and left parenthesis of the outer for-loop.

Comment: @200_success Edited (not that I particularly agree - I find this to be unnecessary over-indentation). I assume what I did is what you meant by the extra spaces note.

Comment: Just as a friendly note, Java normally uses a modified K&R-style with opening braces on the same line. While K&R with opening braces on the same line is mostly used by C#.